# Ng-Table tableParams

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I have am following the first example of ng-table (http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/1).

Everything seems to work except tableParams. As soon as I include it in the controller nothing is display in the page.

The difference between the example and my code is that I load data from a json service:

```
angular.module('mean.cars').controller('CarsController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Global', 'Cars',
function ($scope, $stateParams, $location, Global, Cars, ngTableParams) {
    $scope.global = Global;
    var data = Cars.query();

$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
    page: 1,            // show first page
    count: 10           // count per page
}, {
    total: data.length, // length of data
    getData: function($defer, params) {
        $defer.resolve(data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
    }
});
```

Cars.query(); is working well (tested it).
So what am I missing? 
There is a javascript error: "undefined is not a function occuring" at the following line:

```
$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
```

Comment: I think this this tutorial will help you, it explains exactly what you are trying to do : http://4dev.tech/index.php/2015/08/16/tutorial-basic-datatable-sorting-filtering-and-pagination-with-angularjs-and-ng-table/

Answer (score 21):

I'm also new with Angular and also with ngTable plugin, but I think your problem is that you are not adding the reference for ngTable on your module.

```
angular.module('mean.cars', ['ngTable'])
       .controller('CarsController', ['$scope', 
                                      '$stateParams', 
                                      '$location', 
                                      'Global', 
                                      'Cars', 
                                      'ngTableParams', 
            function ($scope, $stateParams, $location, Global, Cars, ngTableParams) { ...
```

You missed the 'ngTable' on the module dependency, and also the 'ngTableParams' on your controller.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure where ngTableParams comes from, but you're not injecting it:

```
['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Global', 'Cars',
function ($scope, $stateParams, $location, Global, Cars, ngTableParams) {
```

Either that should be like this:

```
['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Global', 'Cars', 'ngTableParams',
function ($scope, $stateParams, $location, Global, Cars, ngTableParams) {
```

Or like this:

```
['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Global', 'Cars',
function ($scope, $stateParams, $location, Global, Cars) {
```

Comment: I did try both solutions but nothing. With the first one I get a jshint error: 'ngTableParams is not defined'

Comment: the first version worked for me, this is listing all field names as strings also ..

Answer (score 0):

Try  this,
Replace your ngTableParams -> NgTableParams
angular.module('mean.cars').controller('CarsController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Global', 'Cars',
function ($scope, $stateParams, $location, Global, Cars, NgTableParams) {

and

$scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({ .It worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

run your service in getData

```
$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
    page: 1,            // show first page
    count: 10           // count per page
}, {
    total: data.length, // length of data
    getData: function($defer, params) {
        data = Cars.query();
        $defer.resolve(data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
    }
});
```

Comment: please explain to the OP why